# Why can't I write this nested for loop as a list comprehension?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have this nested for loop:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, max_row=13, min_col=13, max_col=13):
    for cell in row:
        symbol_cell.append(cell.value)
```

Which I have shortened to this:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, max_row=13, min_col=13, max_col=13):
    [symbol_cell.append(cell.value) for cell in row]
```

And I would like to write the whole thing like this:

```
[symbol_cell.append(cell.value) for cell in row for row in 
 ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, max_row=13, min_col=13, max_col=13)]
```

But I can't, whenever I try to run this code using the third method I get an exception stating that `row` in `min_row & max_row` is undefined. Can someone clarify for me why I can use `iter_rows` in the first two methods, but not the third? I've been learning about comprehensions in python and I've been trying to incorporate them wherever I can.

> Edit:
>   My question was answered in the thread provided by @vaultah

Comment: Don't abuse list comprehensions for side-effects, please. The nested loop is correct.

Comment: Why do you need to collapse this code into a one-liner? It's much, much more readable in the first formulation.

Comment: I understand that the code might be a bit less readable. However I'm on a small team and we all are on the same page with this. I'm trying to speed up this application as its starting to run a bit sluggish. Hence why I'm trying to use list comprehensions where applicable.

Comment: Have you tried to swap the loops before "contesting" the duplicate? The modules that you use are irrelevant.

Comment: @vaultah you are actually correct. I'm going to edit my questions and apologize for jumping the gun. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome :) As others have pointed out, using list comprehensions for side-effects is generally a bad idea. If `symbol_state` is empty initially, you could do `symbol_state = [cell.value for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, max_row=13, min_col=13, max_col=13) for cell in row]` Otherwise, you could convert the list comprehension to generator expression and pass it to `symbol_state.extend`: `symbol_state.extend(cell.value for ...)`.

Comment: Thats the case. I initialize an empty list and then use my code above to populate with values from an excel spreadsheet. I've used your `symbol_state` method as it looks a lot cleaner in my function, thanks!